# T-SQL query results based on count

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

[image]

Given the table above how could I achieve a result where I would only see rows where A has a category, so for example I would see all the rows for CARS AND BIKES but not SCOOTERS because A does not have SCOOTER category.

The 2nd result I would to achieve is just so see rows where there are > 3 distinct OrgNames for a Category.  So for example I would only return rows for BIKES and SCOOTERS because there are more than 3 OrgNames per Category.

Thank you in advance

Comment: try it and let us know the result.

Comment: For the 2nd result I have:

WITH SA_CTE
AS
( 
 SELECT Category,OrgName FROM TEST
)
SELECT 

A.CATEGORY, COUNT(A.ORGNAME)

FROM SA_CTE A
GROUP BY A.CATEGORY
HAVING COUNT(ORGNAME) >3

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Comment: See [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables) for how to format markup tables :)

Comment: The picture needs a wooden table with the printout to be readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand the types of queries you're wanting to create.

Take a look at the code below:

```
DECLARE @ExampleData TABLE (
  OrgName nvarchar(1),
  Category nvarchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @ExampleData (OrgName, Category)
  SELECT DISTINCT
    OrgName,
    Category
  FROM (SELECT
    'A' AS OrgName,
    'CARS' AS Category
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'B' AS OrgName,
    'CARS' AS Category
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'C' AS OrgName,
    'CARS' AS Category
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'A' AS OrgName,
    'BIKES' AS Category
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'D' AS OrgName,
    'BIKES' AS Category
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'E' AS OrgName,
    'BIKES' AS Category
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'F' AS OrgName,
    'BIKES' AS Category
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'Z' AS OrgName,
    'SCOOTERS' AS Category
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'G' AS OrgName,
    'SCOOTERS' AS Category
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'H' AS OrgName,
    'SCOOTERS' AS Category
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'I' AS OrgName,
    'SCOOTERS' AS Category
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'J' AS OrgName,
    'SCOOTERS' AS Category) data

/*
View full recordset
*/
SELECT
  e.*
FROM @ExampleData e
ORDER BY e.Category ASC, e.OrgName ASC

/*
Option 1: Only rows where at least 1 category has an OrgName = 'A'
*/
SELECT
  e.*
FROM @ExampleData e
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
  e.Category
FROM @ExampleData e
WHERE e.OrgName = 'A') cat
  ON cat.Category = e.Category
ORDER BY e.Category ASC, e.OrgName ASC

/*
Option 2: Only see rows where therere are >3 Org Names per category
*/
SELECT
  e.*
FROM @ExampleData e
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
  e.Category,
  COUNT(DISTINCT e.OrgName) AS Count
FROM @ExampleData e
GROUP BY e.Category) cat
  ON cat.Category = e.Category
  AND cat.Count > 3
ORDER BY e.Category ASC, e.OrgName ASC
```

It gives the output below:

[image]